# Issues understanding how to deploy Nuxtjs ( or js in general ) applications with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I know this might appear to be a dump question but I simply cannot understand exactly how the deployment of these javascript applications works.

So basically I am working on an announcements application that obviously needs to have good SEO and most importantly be crawled and indexed by Google. I have been reading about Nuxt and SSR and went off with it.

I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlUZw1J0kwM but I still can't fully understand.

- What's the difference between `npm run build` and `npm run generate`
- One appears to be just an index.html and a bunch of js files (with
  some kind of hashes for names) and the  other has files like (
  `router.js`, `store.js` etc.. ). Also one is in a dist folder and the
  other in some hidden `.nuxt folder`.
- Which one of those are using SSR and whether either one of them can
  be indexed so the announcements actually will start to appear on
  google searches
- Do I also take the whole code on production or only the build/generate files

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make ssr app you should use `npm run build` and nuxt will build your app otherwise if you want to deploy your code in spa mode or static (like github pages) you can use `npm run generate` so nuxt generate some html code for you

according to [nuxtjs documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands/):

nuxt build => Build your application with webpack and minify the JS & CSS (for production).

nuxt generate => Build the application and generate every route as a HTML file (used for static hosting).